# Rails Search Query Associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In [railscast #37](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form) they show a simple search I am trying to implement. I have the following association:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dogs
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner
end
```

The Dog model has an attribute "name" and so does the owner. I need to be able to filter a list of dogs so that if you type "Fido" (dog) or "Bob" (owner) Fido will show up in the list. Here is how the search is currently set up:

model dog.rb:

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
end
```

this will return ONLY search terms matching the dog name (owner name is ignored)

I tried to change it to something like this:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ? or owner.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

However is says there is no owner column. How do I change the search condition to be able to search both dog name and owner name?

Comment: Which rails version are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that by following Rails convention you have tables named `dogs` for `Dog` model and `owners` for `Owner` model.

Update the `search` method as below:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      joins(:owner).where('dogs.name LIKE ? or owners.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

You need a join query between `dogs` and `owners` table in order to access `owners.name` field

Comment: Kirti: 1 / MrYoshiji : 0 ... You're too quick to answer!