# Rails: Search by params not working -- issue with associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, model-view-controller, parameters

I am building a Rails application which allows users to search for Books by Author's name. I am having some problems building the search function, but to my knowledge, I felt that I was doing things exactly right?

Here is what I am starting with:
schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "author_name"
    t.index ["title"], name: "index_books_on_title", unique: true
  end

  create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "bio"
  end
end
```

Here are my sample data in seeds.rb

```
books = [
          {title:"Ruby Programming", author_id: 1, author_name: "John Smith"},
          {title:"Java Programming", author_id: 2 , author_name: "Jane Adams"},
          {title:"PHP Programming", author_id: 3, author_name: "Mike Jones"},
          {title:"Python Programming", author_id: 1, author_name: "John Smith"}
        ]

authors = [
            {name:"John Smith", bio: "John Smith loves Ruby and Python"},
            {name:"Jane Adams", bio: "Jane Adams loves Java"},
            {name:"Mike Jones", bio: "Mike Jones loves PHP"}
          ]
```

Here is my books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Books.all
    if params[:search]
      @books = Book.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @books = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end    
end
```

Here is my models/book.rb. Here is where I'm defining the search function.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :author

  def author_name
    self.author.name
  end

  def self.search(search)
    where("book.author.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
  end
end
```

And here is my models/author.rb

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end
```

Here is where the user is able to search for books by author name, in views/books/index.html.erb

```
<h3> Search by author </h3>

<%= form_tag(books_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search by Author" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

<ul>
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <li>
     <%= link_to book.title book_path(book) %>          
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

However, when I type in an author (using the example "John Smith"), I keep on getting an error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: book.author.name: SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE (book.author.name LIKE '%John Smith%') ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I suspect that in models/book.rb, I am not defining the search function correctly. Does anyone have any suggestion for what might be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your search method in `models/book.rb`:

```
def self.search(search)
    where("book.author.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
end
```

Since you're searching the book model, you've got the column name wrong, you're after `book.author_name`, not `book.author.name`.

Try the following:

```
def self.search(search)
    where("book.author_name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
end
```

You may also want to consider having a look at your database design as you store the author's name in multiple tables. It'd be a good idea to normalise your database design further by just referencing the author ID in the book model, then keeping the author name in the author model.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm actually trying to do just what you suggested...I'm trying to reference the author's name directly through the Book's association with author_id. Any suggestions for doing it through that?

Comment: When trying to access data from a related table, you need to use a join query between the two tables in order to find the right records. This answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22970800/6026888) shows a join query being used in a simple example. This essentially makes a theoretical table where books and author information is stored, and you can search through that to return books based on the author.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues that I found in your code. May be, fixing them would solve the error for you.

#### Association in model Book

You have a correctly defined association in model `Author` that is has many books. The inverse of it should be defined as [`belongs_to`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference), and not `has_one`. Change it to following:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

#### Redundant/Unused column in books table

As per your database schema, you have a column *author_name* in *books* table. But, instead of fetching its value directly, you have defined your own getter method `author_name`, which returns `author.name`. So, if you really want to have the column there in *books* table, remove the custom method `author_name` from model.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  # def author_name
  #   self.author.name
  # end
end
```

#### Searching

The error you see is because there is no table *book* (singular). Change your `search` method to as below and it should work:

```
def self.search(search)
  where("author_name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
end
```

**Note:** This solution assumes you kept the column *author_name* intentionally in table *books*. I will recommend dropping the column *author_name* though and search for *name* in associated `authors` table.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of changes in your code:

**1. Relation inside Book model**

It should be `belongs_to :author` instead of `has_one :author` .

**2. Modify search block**

Remove the redundant author_name method from the Book model.

The search part can be done in two ways:

- With author_name column inside books table.
- Without author_name column inside books table since it is already present in the author record.

For first case simple modify you search method as follow:

```
def self.search(search)
  where("author_name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
end
```

Better to add an index on author_name.

For second case, remove the author_name column from books table and modify the code as follows:

```
def self.search(search)
  author_ids = Author.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%").ids
  where(author_id: author_ids)
end
```

Again, better to add an index on author_name inside authors table.

Another suggestion, do case insensitive search to improve searches as follows:

```
where("lower(author_name) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%")
```

Hope this helps.