# Search in computed value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named 'Project' which has a field 'label' and is associated with another model named 'Contacts' (one-to-many). Said contacts can be either clients or adversaries.

Each project is given a name, built by taking the first client, the first adversary, and appending a label after. For example: 'Robt Dickinson et al. v. Hoeger et al.: hostile takeover' (see `build_project_name` below).

Here's the model, reduced for brevity:

```rb
#app/models/project.rb

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  FORMATS = {
    heading:   'cases<span class=\"mute\">&nbsp;&sol;&nbsp;</span>#{build_project_name}',
    name:      '#{build_project_name}',
    long_name: '#{build_project_name}<span class=\"mute\"><span class=\"no-calt\">:</span>&nbsp;</span>#{label}',
  }

  has_and_belongs_to_many :adversaries, -> { adversaries }, class_name: "Contact"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients, -> { clients }, class_name: "Contact"

  scope :label_contains,     -> (str) { where('label LIKE ?', "%#{str}%") }
  scope :reference_contains, -> (str) { where('reference LIKE ?', "%#{str}%") }
  scope :search,             -> (str) { label_contains(str).or(reference_contains(str)) }

  def combine(format = :name)
    eval('"' + FORMATS[format.to_sym] + '"').gsub(/^\s*(?:<br\s*\/?\s*>)+|(?:<br\s*\/?\s*>)+\s*$/i, "").gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip.html_safe
  end

  private

  def build_project_name
    str  = ""
    str += clients.first.combine(:name) if clients.exists?
    str += "&nbsp;<span class=\"mute\">et al.</span>" if clients.count > 1
    str += "<span class=\"mute\">&nbsp;v.&nbsp;</span>" if clients.exists? && adversaries.exists?
    str += adversaries.first.combine(:name) if adversaries.exists?
    str += "&nbsp;<span class=\"mute\">et al.</span>" if adversaries.count > 1
    str.html_safe
  end
end
```

In layman's term, I want to be able to perform the following search: 'is John included in built title?'.

In other words, I should perform a `where()` on the first of the associated clients and adversaries. Any ideas how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: Not sure about searching the *first* relation, but normally this would be done using `join` and updating the query appropriately, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/22970699/438992. There's probably similar semantics for only searching the first, but I don't know what it is :/ Unrelated, but building HTML in a model is a definite anti-pattern--seems like a canonical place for a decorator if there's some reason a simple helper won't do.

Comment: if you only search the firsts you might as well do it in ruby and not sql, e.g clients.first.name.include?('john') || aversaries.first.name.include?('john'). I don't see a big benefit in trying to do this in one sql query

Comment: @JoelBlum I absolutely agree. But how to you include the results in the already existing :search scope?

Comment: Heads up! Your `build_project_name` is a school example of how to get an XSS attack. If you REALLY want to build HTML like that you should ONLY call to `.html_safe` on the chunks of HTML that are actually safe. For example `str += "&nbsp;<span class=\"mute\">et al.</span>".html_safe`. Don't concatenate user input + html and call `.html_safe` on the whole thing. Better yet move this outside the model as recommended by @DaveNewton and use a partial or the tag helpers which do this automatically. https://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong

Comment: Haha nice, thanks for the input! This function started out as a “nice to have” feature and ended up being a convoluted piece of exploitable code. At least I learned something 

Comment: @MalcolmIsaacson the use of eval here is also pretty scary. If you ever want to do "string templates" like this use  [`Kernel#sprintf`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Kernel:sprintf) instead of string interpolation. But there are much better ways to build HTML in Rails apps.

Comment: Thanks @max, though sprintf seems rather targeted at formatting shorter numbers instead of longer text strings, so I don’t really see the use in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this?

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :adversaries, -> { where(role_name: 'adversary') }, class_name: "Contact"
has_and_belongs_to_many :clients, -> { where(role_name: 'client') }, class_name: "Contact"
```